# EKS: Route external VPC traffic to service ClusterIP using kube-proxy (or something else)?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kube-proxy

**Requirement/Problem:**

I would like to route traffic from the VPC network to a cluster IP.  In AKS I was able to do this by adding an entry in the VNET route table to a node running kube-proxy.  I can't seem to be able to do this in EKS.  I would like to do this for development environments so I can easily access service cluster IPs without having to forward ports or create load balancers.  It's my understanding that kube-proxy uses iptables to forward network traffic.

**Question:**

Is there something fundamental that won't allow me to route traffic to the cluster network in EKS?

**Context:**

I'm testing with eks.9 and k8s 1.21

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you should definitely be able to do this by setting proper `SecurityGroup` settings (which allow traffic to be forwarded to your worker node `clusterIP` subnet).

And yes, `kube-proxy` uses `iptables` to forward traffic but it really depends on the `overlay` networking driver you have. If you're running `flannel` for instance, this is true, but perhaps not for `calico` or `cilium`, they may use `bpf`. So, just double check if your overlay network CNI plugin supports forwarding based on `iptables`.

Another thing you can do (and this will not require creating Load Balancers) is you can change your service type to `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` which will allow you to set a personalized `externalIP` on your service. This you can provide to the cluster through a subnet configured in your VPC. All the incoming traffic to this subnet will then be forwarded to your services on the desired ports on which they are listening.

I hope this is helpful enough for you to get started.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't believe it's a problem with SGs, as I'm able to reach the worker nodes fine, and for testing enabled all ingress traffic.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think it might be helpful now.